# Utopia city, a place with no poverty

Tags: economy

I was researching how a fantasy city would in theory reduce poverty to 0, and found out that China reduced poverty down to 0%... from the year 2000 when 49% of the population was living below the poverty line to 2020 where it was reduced to 0%. [At least according to "our world in data"](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/share-of-population-living-in-poverty-by-national-poverty-lines?tab=table&time=2000..latest&country=HND%7EPOL) and [World Bank](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SI.POV.NAHC?view=map&year_high_desc=true)

So my question would be, did I misread the stats, am I lacking the necessary understanding to get what it means, like can an actual city, town, country or even empire achieve complete lack of poverty?

Let me rephrase the question, if a fantasy place had the **primary** goal of eradicating:

- Starvation [as defined by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation)
- Illiteracy caused by lack of money/resources
- Criminality caused by lack of money/resources

Could this be achieved? If so can it only be achieved in socialist countries or countries exactly like China?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @L.Dutch.

Comment: TL;DR for my answer below: you did read the stats wrong.

Comment: Shopper: "I thought everything here is 2 dollar" Manager: "mdm read carefully it says with a min. spent of 200 dollars, NEXT!"

Comment: Criminality is a state of mind. Criminality is about radically not conforming to social norms. About 1% of humanity is criminal no matter how much money they might have. To eliminate criminality means to eliminate those people from society (jail, exile, or death).

Answer (score 10):

Cheating the statistics is pretty easy, if you know how to play with them.

Example: if you have a polluting industry in city A which causes an increase of cancer among the inhabitants if A, you can hide that if you count the number of deceases caused by cancer in each hospital and make sure that city A doesn't have an oncology center: all the sick people will move to get treated and die in other cities, spreading the numbers.

You can play similar tricks with the definition of poverty but, hey, it's fantasy city, so it's up to you if you want it to be dilly dally perfect with jasmine scented sewers and no crime, so be it.

By the way, no poverty does not mean no crime. A big shot of the underworld in my home town wasn't poor, had gold taps in his mansion and made money selling drugs to the riches. No poors were involved in his business.

Comment: In fact, when I was a teenager attending summer science programs at a local university, the most popular class was "lying with statistics."

Comment: "There are 3 kinds of lies: White Lies, Damn Lies, and Statistics" ~ My college statistics professor

Answer (score 7):

Building up on [L.Dutch' answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/255699/21222), I am going to add three examples in literature. From the most obscure to the most popular:

1. *Nine Planets Without Intelligent Life*'s Uranus orbital station;
2. *Attack On Titan*'s kingdom within the walls, and;
3. *Avatar: The Last Airbender*'s Ba Sing Se.

Each of these is a State with a circular layout. They are all architectured so that the rich live either on top (NPWIL) or at the center of the State. The poor either live within outermost layer,  confined by giant walls that make them invisible from outside the slums (AoT, ATLA) or literally and permanently hidden and trapped below the street (NPWIL).

When doing a census in any of those examples, as long as you don't conduct your surveys and queries around the poorer places, your results will show a State that has a very gigh Human Development Index and where everybofy is wealthy.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

So, "eliminating poverty" depends on the definition.  China eliminated poverty *based on its definition of poverty*, which was [earning less than $2.30 (USD 2011 parity) per day.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poverty_in_China).

By the global definition of poverty for a country with China's per-capita GDP, circa 13% of the population is still in poverty.

This is not to belittle China's achievements in lifting people out of the deepest extremes of poverty, but there are definitely still poor people in China.

### However

Other countries (particularly Nordic ones) have had a great deal of success in reducing and eliminating poverty.  [Iceland in particular](https://www.borgenmagazine.com/inside-the-countries-with-the-lowest-poverty-rates) hit 0% poverty by the global measure in 2017.

Social safety nets, welfare, and other socialist measures are key in making this possible, but the country need not be wholly or mostly communist or socialist, it need only be rich and determined.

Since we have examples IRL other than China, we can say that a) it is possible, and b) assuming that a lack of resources is the only cause of the ills you list, they would indeed be eliminated.  (Criminality is a very complex study, and plainly would not be entirely eliminated just by making sure no one was poor.)

Comment: thanks but I'm not saying that people only kill and thief for money or resources, just mentioned it because it is usually the reason most likely to bring the common folk towards crime, at least in the cities I've lived in

Answer (score 4):

In modern times, in the so-called *Global North*, poverty is usually defined as **relative poverty.** There are different benchmarks, but poverty usually happens below 40% or 60% of the median income. Imagine there is a public school, and 20 kids in the class got new brand-name sneakers, and 5 kids can only afford scuffed no-name shoes. Kids being kids, those five will be discriminated against because of their visible poverty.

Removing poverty in these terms calls for a relatively equal distribution of wealth from the upper middle class down. A few rich people, even 10% or 20% rich people, will not shift the median income all that much. In the example above, there would be 5 kids in the class who can afford expensive brand-name sneakers, or who would not be on that public school to start with, and 20 kids with relatively equal wealth at the lower level.

In medieval terms, if 9 in 10 people are peasants, and all of them are equally poor and oppressed, you have no poverty.

But in your question, you defined poverty in **both relative and absolute terms**.

Getting **enough food** is a question of agricultural productivity (including things like fertilizers, pesticides, and farm machinery), and food redistribution on a continental scale to overcome regional shortages. That requires 20th century technology. All earlier societies will run the risk of the occasional famine.

You cannot bring enough grain from a surplus area to a famine area by oxcart. The oxen would eat more (either roadside grass or grain from their cargo) than they deliver. You need ships, and suitable sea lanes or canals, or you need railways.

The **literacy** standard, on the other hand, is probably one of public policy. If at least a primary-school-level education is expected for all children, most societies can find the resources to have teachers, and to free kids aged 6-10 from work at least most of the day.

The question of **crime** driven by poverty is very much one of relative poverty, not absolute poverty, unless one *expects* poor people to be satisfied with just-above-starvation food while others have a feast. It is very much an issue of social opportunities and social expectations -- are parents telling their kids *'go to school, learn something, get a job like me?'* and is that a realistic proposal?

Answer (score 3):

Not quite the utopia, but...

Poverty can be eliminated by lifting those impoverished out of poverty by enlisting them in a well-equipped police force. These police would receive rations and pay from government systems, as well as education and training. Resources are acquired through colonies.

In turn, these police would eradicate crime by force.

Answer (score 2):

### One Man's Utopia Is Always another's Dystopia

Can magic create nearly unlimited resources? Sure.  Can those resources be used to eliminate poverty, to a large degree, yes.  But will the resulting society be an actually utopia ... probably not.

No matter how you organize your society, someone is going to suffer.

**Option 1: Mages are rare, and enjoy absolute authority**

By driving out the factors of fair trade that make poverty possible, it means that no one can any longer sustain themselves.  Craftsmen can no longer sell items that take them days to craft if mages can make them with a snap of their fingers and just give them away.  Farmers won't tend thier lands if mages can fill the markets with produce out of thin air.

This means that the mages will have such unlimited power over people, that half the time they are abusing people, they won't even be aware of it.  The woman a mage thinks he's just dating is actually terrified to leave him because she does not want to lose her food rations.  The town guards are willing to bend any laws to help a mage out because they don't want to lose thier homes. No one is willing to speak against the magocracy because they don't want to be turned into a newt.  So on the surface, the mages look out on thier society and see perfection, but under that thin facade is a reign of terror that they are simply too high in thier ivory towers to see.

**Option 2: Mages are rare, and suffer under absolute control**

If the mages are not in charge, then they are the tools of who ever is.  Each mage represents such a pivotal part of the economy that they are forced to use thier magic to keep up utopian appearances. They are pressed by thier masters to churn out an endless supply of consumer goods that the masses consume. In this scenario, there is less fear of the chain of supplies being cut off, but it becomes the mages themselves who suffer, being constantly milked "for the greater good".

**Option 3: Mages are common, and traditional social classes emerge anyway**

Look at a modernized nation like the United States.  Technology means that the average person today enjoys 5 times as much wealth as a person 100 years ago, and yet we still have large poverty stricken populations and homelessness issues.  This is because the definition of poverty has shifted.  Less than 1% of people will ever starve to death or die from lack of shelter, but we still consider a large portion of the population as improvised because they are poor by the standards of today.  Likewise, you will have some mages that are rich and powerful, and those that can barely cast a minor mending spell. Even if those lesser mages enjoy better living conditions than 90% of people living outside of your utopia, all they will be able to see is how poor and miserable they are compared to the people they see and know.

### What this means for your exact question

It means that magic can eliminate starvation, but the other problems maybe, maybe not.

In a world of Magic, maybe there will be more leisure time for learning, or... literacy may be more strongly controlled to limit access to knowledge that leads to magic.  Or, if reading is not necessary for magic, then reading becomes far less useful across the board, and may not been seen as an important part of education at all.

As for crime, it's also hard to say one way or the other.  On the 1 hand, magic could be used to better find and convict criminals, or it could have the opposite outcome.  Crime is more of a result of desperation and frustration than actual needs.  If people are stressed all the time from pretending to be happy so they don't upset the mages, then that stress could come out in other ways leading to increased domestic violence, vandalism, assault, and terrorism.

### Magic does not make your goals any more or less achievable

Starvation and literacy can be solved without any need for magic, communism, or modern industry.  The Imperial era city of Rome did this.

They solved starvation through thier system of bread handouts, slavery, and beggary... again, I would NOT call this a Utopia, but it does in a minimal sense meet your  first goal.  Not matter how rich or poor you were, the Emperor guaranteed bread handouts to every person who lived in the city.  This made starving to death in the city virtually impossible.  Also, the demand for slaves was high.  Anyone who found themselves out of resources to survive could sell themselves or certain family members into slavery.  Because there were laws that required a certain level of care for debt slaves, this further ensured shelter for the would-be homeless community.  Rome also gave out licenses to beggars.  If you were disabled making you too worthless as a slave to be able to find a master, you could get a license to legally sit in public places like the entrance to a temple to beg for money.  Because begging was a licensed profession, there was not the stereotype of beggars in ancient Rome just being too lazy to work; so, they were generally treated with more respect than they are today.  Licensed beggars typically made more money than the average lower class worker; so, thier earnings were generally enough to hold off starvation, and pay for the care they needed.

As for literacy, many of the inscriptions and records from Ancient Rome are clearly written by or too the lower class and slaves; so, basic literacy had to have been very common.  It was seen everywhere: every business, public building, grave stone, and street sign had written inscriptions, and there were laws requiring every business and government organization to kept written records which would be an impossible law if litteracy was not very common.  Under the tradition of Pater Familia, it was expected that each head of household teach his sons and servants enough reading, writing, and arithmetic to engage in basic business and legal transactions.  The key here is "servants".  The debt slaves I mentioned earlier were a part of one's household; so, even if you were an illiterate slave, you could expect enough education to achieve the level of literacy required by your the job that you were appointed. Writing was less standardized in Ancient Rome than it is today; so, if you spelled a certain word a little differently than someone else, it was not seen as a big deal.  But literacy about on par with an average 1st or 2nd grader today was very common without any need for a public education system.

Criminality caused by a lack of money/resources on the other hand is an unsolvable no matter how much wealth and magic you throw at the problem.  People at every tier of society, no matter how much money and resources they have, will always be tempted to commit crimes to achieve more money and resources.  History is littered with examples of Princes, Kings, and Emperors murdering and stealing to cement thier power.  Wealthy billionaires commit fraud and tax evasion to bolster up thier fortunes.  Even in China, it is common for people to illegally invest in foreign markets to create personal wealth. The only way to have no crime is to have no laws... but then you are left with anarchy.

Answer (score 2):

**Asking if it's possible in real life isn't relevant. What's relevant is whether or not you can achieve the goal in your imaginary world such that people can suspend their disbelief.**

As has been pointed out by others, achieving "0% poverty" has more to do with defining what "0% poverty" means than it does anything else. The first problem is that it *sounds simple* but in reality it's *incredibly complex.* Considering only a family's finances, The U.S. defines the "poverty line" as...

| Family size | 2023 income numbers | 2024 income numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| For a family of 2 | \$19,720 | \$20,440 |
| For a family of 3 | \$24,860 | \$25,820 |
| For a family of 4 | \$30,000 | \$31,200 |
| For a family of 5 | \$35,140 | \$36,580 |

One simple question, "What's the poverty line?" and there's 12 points of data. Nothing about the concept of "0% poverty" is simple. Literacy? To what level? For the purpose of reading street signs? Government documents? Scientific articles? Starvation? Based on calories? Proteins? Regionally available foods? To support a laborer? Athlete? Scientist? Criminality? To the point people participate in creating law? Who says that any particular crime is based on "poverty?"

It's a mess in reality. The closest we've reasonably come to "0% poverty" is the idea of [post-scarcity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-scarcity), which isn't actually a means to "0% poverty" unless you define it (aka declare it) to be so. "Post-scarcity" is nothing more than taking advantage of technology to ensure that everyone has a defined set of needs met: everybody has a bed, a plate and fork, rudimentary food... but for every person who is eternally grateful to have those things there is another who thinks they're still impoverished if only because someone else has more than they do.

**So, worldbuilding...**

The goal isn't scientific (or sociological... or economic...) fact but suspension of disbelief. What do we need to achieve that?

1. Your society, with the exception of the inevitable few, should be content, if not happy.
2. Your society, regardless specific comparisons with other cultures, should be considered productive and economically stable.
3. Politics will always have detractors, but whatever political system you choose, it should support basic freedoms (whatever that means), participation by the public (whatever that means), and a means of resolving conflict in a way that's defensible to the public (yup, whatever that means).

And how do you do all that?

- By managing the production and distribution of food to meet the needs of the many over the few, despite the tendency in any society for the few to acquire power over the many.
- By managing the distribution and flow of wealth to balance the necessities of all while rewarding the meritorious behavior of some and quietly accepting the inevitability that the clever will obtain the most.
- By structuring your political and judicial systems to preserve the ... Who am I kidding? This is the most difficult part of the whole thing for a worldbuilder to craft. Political systems can be boiled down outrageously to this: the need to balance the freedoms of the individual with the needs of society. The only practical resource a political system has to do this is the threat of violence (a fine is just another form of violence). Obviously it's all a whomping lot more complex than this, but it's a start. Winston Churchill made a really deep point when he said:

> Many forms of Government have been tried, and will be tried in this world of sin and woe. No one pretends that democracy is perfect or all-wise. Indeed it has been said that democracy is the worst form of Government except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time.…

In other words, no political system is perfect. No political system can guarantee 0% poverty. From another point of view, any political system can be structured to believably justify the achievement of the goal.

- Finally, and perhaps most importantly, for ***you*** to decide for yourself what it means to have "0% poverty" and then begin working through how you can justify that declaration with reasonable simplifications of real world constructs. This is very much the most difficult part of this worldbuilding exercise, because it requires you to answer the question, "what if?" If you think about it, nobody else can answer that for you.

---

***NOTE:** I have made this answer a community wiki, which means I won't profit from the answer. However, I think the OP has asked a question that deserves a more canonical answer than we usually provide. Anyone and everyone is welcome to edit this answer to improve it with this goal in mind: what are the rules, steps, choices, and opportunities a worldbuilder must address to develop a believable post-scarcity or "0% poverty" society? I look forward to your input!*

Answer (score 0):

You have a goal of eradicating the Hungry, the Illiterate, and the Criminal.

One option for an authoritarian regime to do so is to directly eliminate those that are hungry, those that are illiterate, and those that are criminal.

Killing them would be one way to do so, but there are less cold-blooded ways of doing so.

They could have a social services task force who gather up all of the hungry, illiterate, and criminal and enroll them into workhouses that keep them fed, educated, and out of trouble; whether thay want the help or not.

Comment: While this is not untrue... it does not really address the relationship between magic and utopian societies.

Comment: @Nosajimiki While the question mentioned a fantasy city, is there anything in the question requiring a connection between magic and utopia?

Comment: On this site at least, Fantasy and Magic are considered synonymous.  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms